# HAProxy url_beg/path_beg doesnt seem to work

Tags: haproxy

My haproxy.cfg is this

```
frontend go 127.0.0.1:8081
    timeout client 86400000
    acl ddos_log path_beg /ddoslogger/
    use_backend ddos_backend        if ddos_log
    use_backend normal_backend      if !ddos_log

backend ddos_backend
    mode http
    option httplog
    balance uri
    # Will add more servers if this works
    server  go11 localhost:8083 check
    server  go11 localhost:8083 backup

backend normal_backend
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option allbackups
    default-server weight 50 slowstart 30s inter 3s fastinter 2s downinter 5s
    server  go10 localhost:8082 check
    server  go10 localhost:8082 backup
```

What I planned to do basically was for all queries to "/ddoslogger/", I will use the balance uri method to select server, and for others use a different load balancing approach. Both talk to the same set of servers (I have removed others for debugging purposes)

Heres what I get when I made a request to haproxy in debug mode

```
00000000:go.accept(0004)=0006 from [127.0.0.1:58054]
00000000:normal_backend.clireq[0006:ffff]: POST /ddoslogger/a01324jlkas HTTP/1.1
00000000:normal_backend.clihdr[0006:ffff]: Host: localhost:8081
00000000:normal_backend.clihdr[0006:ffff]: Connection: keep-alive
00000000:normal_backend.clihdr[0006:ffff]: Content-Length: 204
00000000:normal_backend.clihdr[0006:ffff]: Cache-Control: no-cache
00000000:normal_backend.clihdr[0006:ffff]: Origin: chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm
00000000:normal_backend.clihdr[0006:ffff]: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36
00000000:normal_backend.clihdr[0006:ffff]: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
00000000:normal_backend.clihdr[0006:ffff]: Accept: */*
00000000:normal_backend.clihdr[0006:ffff]: Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
00000000:normal_backend.clihdr[0006:ffff]: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
00000000:normal_backend.clihdr[0006:ffff]: Cookie: <truncated>
00000000:normal_backend.srvrep[0006:0007]: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
00000000:normal_backend.srvhdr[0006:0007]: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
00000000:normal_backend.srvhdr[0006:0007]: Content-Length: 0
00000000:normal_backend.srvhdr[0006:0007]: Date: Thu, 19 Sep 2013 03:55:19 GMT
```

Any Suggestions for what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this by moving

```
mode http
option httplog
```

to the frontend service, so it looks like this now:

```
frontend go 127.0.0.1:8081
    timeout client 86400000
    mode http
    option httplog
    acl ddos_log path_beg /ddoslogger/
    use_backend ddos_backend        if ddos_log
    use_backend normal_backend      if !ddos_log
.
.
.
```

In case others are struggling with this!

Comment: `mode http` worked for me as well.